# How to tell if a column is text or long when 'mediumtext' is returned for long from information_schema.columns table?

Tags: mysql

I'm reading information_schema tables for MySql for a schema I'm working with that has tables that have long as a data type.

As in

create table foo (
col1 varchar(40),
col2 long,
col3 varchar(256)
);

If I do a select from information_schema.columns on this table the data_type comes back as 'mediumtext'.

How can I tell the difference between a long and a text field?

Example sql is shown below:

```
drop table if exists foo;

create table foo (
  col1 varchar(40),
  col2 long,
  col3 varchar(256),
  col4 mediumtext
);

insert into foo values ("This is col 1", 12345, 'This is col 3', 'This is col4');

select * from foo;

select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'foo';
```

Comment: Interestingly if you define col2 as longtext then that's how it will appear when you query information_schema.columns. long is not a defined datatype but doesn't cause an error and seems to be a synonym for mediumtext.

Answer (score 0):

If you define col2 as longtext then that's how it will appear when you query information_schema.columns. long is not a defined datatype in mysql but 'To facilitate the use of code written for SQL implementations from other vendors' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html it maps as mediumtext.